# mcu gprs connection with google geolocation API

Tags: c, geolocation, gprs, cellid

I need to use Google Maps Geolocation API based on cell towers using a GPRS module which has Embedded TCP/IP Stack, FTP，HTTP and so on (HUAWEI MG323-B).
The module is communicating with an MCU (LPC1115) via UART.

Is it possible to implement the required "Google Maps Geolocation API" just between the MCU/GSM Module and the Google Server ?
Which PDP address should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, I suppose, but I doubt you will get a solution in form of useful code, since there is a lot of work.
Google Maps Geolocation API require array of "cellTower" objects, which represents all cell towers, visible to the GSM/GPRS module. So, you simply get them from the module, form a json request and that's it.